# Why is this recursive map function only being applied to the last two elements in the list?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, map-function, lazy-sequences

This is the problem given: What are the first 8 elements in the following list?

```
mystery = 0 : 10 : (map(+1)mystery)
```

The answer is `[0,10,1,11,2,12,3,13...]`

But in my opinion the answer should be `[0,10,1,11,1,11,2,12]`. The following steps show why:

1) We are given ;list `[0,10]` so after applying the function the first time we have the list [`0,10,1, 11]`
2) Now we have a list [`0,10,1,11]` so after applying the function again the resulting list should be `[0,10,1,11,1,11,2,12]`

Apparently that is not the case. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What function is it *exactly* that you claim is being applied when you write "after applying the function the first time"?

Comment: "Why is this recursive map function only being applied to the last two elements in the list?". It's being applied to every element in the list, but only once - your version seems to apply it to 0 and 10 twice and I can't figure out why you would think it should. Also the list is infinite so it doesn't have a "last 2 elements"

Comment: You never have a list `[0, 10]`; you have a list that *begins* with `0` and `10`, followed by... something. Conceptually, you have to distinguish between appending to a finite list "forever", and applying some function to each element of an initially infinite list.

Answer (score 6):

Before diving into the definition of `mystery`, let's take a look at one of the laws `map` obeys:

```
map f (map g xs) == map (f . g) xs
```

A rather informal proof of this law is easy to follow:

```
map f (map g [x1, x2, ..., xn]) == map f [g x1, g x2, ..., g xn]
                                == [f (g x1), f (g x2), ..., f (g xn)]
                                == [(f.g) x1, (f.g) x2, ..., (f.g) xn]
                                == map (f.g) [x1, x2, ..., xn]
```

---

With that in mind, let's expand `mystery` step by step:

```
mystery == 0 : 10 : map (+1) mystery
        -- by definition of mystery
        == 0 : 10 : map (+1) (0 : 10 : map (+1) mystery)
        -- by definition of map and the fact that  0 + 1 == 1
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : map (+1) (10 : map (+1) mystery)
        -- by definition of map and the fact that 10 + 1 == 11
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : 11 : map (+1) (map (+1) mystery)
        -- using the law above, and the fact that (+1) . (+1) == (+2)
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : 11 : map (+2) mystery
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : 11 : map (+2) (0 : 10 : map (+1) mystery)
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : 11 : 2 : map (+2) (10 : map (+1) mystery)
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : 11 : 2 : 12 : map (+2) (map (+1) mystery)
        == 0 : 10 : 1 : 11 : 2 : 12 : map (+3) mystery
        -- etc
```

You don't start with a finite list `[0, 10]`; you start with an infinite list that *begins* with 0 and 10, with the remaining elements defined recursively.

In some sense, there is no closed form for the list, but that doesn't matter; laziness means that you only apply `map` to `mystery` as needed to get requested items. For example, neither `head mystery` nor `head (tail mystery)` ever need to evaluate the call to `map`, and `head (tail (tail mystery))` only needs to map `(+1)` to the `head mystery`, not the entire infinite list.

Laziness blurs the distinction between the list and the algorithm to *compute* the list.

Comment: Great explanation. It should be mentioned that this explains why `mystery` has the value it has, but it does *not* explain how `mystery` is actually evaluated. In particular, `map (+1) mystery` is only calculated *once*, not once for every two elements.

Answer (score 4):

Let's just work through it, using the recursive definition of `map`:

```
map _ [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Since we have

```
mystery = 0:10:(map (+1) mystery)
```

we already know that

```
mystery = [0, 10, ...]
```

and the `...` stands for `map (+1) mystery`. So let's use the definition above to calculate it.

The list we're applying it to clearly isn't empty - it starts with 0 and 10. So we use the second line, with `x` as 0 and `xs` as `10:(map (+1) mystery)`:

```
map (+1) mystery = 1:(map (+1) (10:(map (+1) mystery)))
```

or, using the formula again for the first level of nesting:

```
map (+1) mystery = 1:11:(map (+1) (map (+1) mystery))
```

So, going back to `mystery` itself, we now know its first 4 elements:

```
mystery = [0, 10, 1, 11, ...]
```

and the `...` stands for the contents of `map (+1) (map (+1) mystery)`. That is, based on the result above:

```
map (+1) (1:11:(map (+1) (map (+1) mystery)))
```

I'll spare you the details of the evaluation here, because it should be clear by now what happens: the first 2 elements (which will be the 5th and 6th in `mystery`) will be 2 and 12, and the rest will be `map (+1) ((map (+1) (map (+1) mystery)))`. Which, by exactly the same process, will start with 3 and 13. And so it goes on, as far as you could ever care to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
mystery = 0 : 10 : map (+1) mystery
```

by the definitions of `(!!)` and `(:)` and `map` it is the case that

```
mystery !! 0 = 0          -- pseudocode
mystery !! 1 = 10
mystery !! n | n > 1
             = (0 : 10 : map (+1) mystery) !! n
             = (10 : map (+1) mystery) !! (n-1)
             = (map (1+) mystery) !! (n-2)
             = 1 + (mystery !! (n-2))
```

and there's your answer.

An illustration:

```
--         0   1  2   3  4   5  6        -- n
mystery = [0, 10, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, ...
--               /   /  /   /  /         -- (+1)
--              [0, 10, 1, 11, 2, ...
--               0   1  2   3  4         -- n-2
```

so all this is, is each element being defined with the reference to a previous one, two positions prior.

Thus another way to write the same thing down, making the pairing up (nay *zipping*) explicit, is

```
mystery = 0 : 10 : zipWith (+) (repeat 1)
                               mystery
-- and in general,
-- map (f y) xs  ==  zipWith f (repeat y) xs
```

Translated into an imperative pseudocode, the program

```
main = print mystery
```

is actually the same as

```
main :
    a = 0
    b = 10
    print "[" 
    while( True ) :
       print a , 
       print b ,
       a += 1
       b += 1
```

---

A *principled* approach to tackle such problems is to *name* all your *interim entities,* the inner *thunks* behind lazy data constructors (here, `:`), as they come into being, forced into WHNF by the demands of lazy evaluation. Then the mystery disappears:

```
mystery = 0  : 10 : map (+1) mystery
        = x1 : t1 
  where 
  x1 = 0
  t1 = 10 : map (+1) mystery
     = x2 : t2
    where
    x2 = 10
    t2 = map (+1) mystery
       = map (+1) (x1 : t1)
       = x1 + 1 : map (1+) t1         -- by definition of map
       = x3     : t3
      where
      x3 = x1 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
      t3 = map (1+) t1 = map (1+) (x2 : t2)
         = x2 + 1 : map (1+) t2       --    = x_{n} + 1 : ...
         = x4     : t4                --    = x_{n+2}   : ...
        where
        ....
```

At no point do we get any function other than `(1+)` in this reduction process, nor do we ever get more than one of them stacked up in a row.

All we get is `xn := 1 + xn-2`, repeatedly, for all `n` above `1`.